# Returning an argument passed by rvalue reference

Tags: c++, return, move-semantics, pass-by-rvalue-reference

If I have a class `A` and functions

```
A f(A &&a)
{
  doSomething(a);
  return a;
}
A g(A a)
{
  doSomething(a);
  return a;
}
```

the copy constructor is called when returning `a` from `f`, but the move constructor is used when returning from `g`. However, from what I understand, `f` can only be passed an object that it is safe to move (either a temporary or an object marked as moveable, e.g., using `std::move`). Is there any example when it would not be safe to use the move constructor when returning from `f`? Why do we require `a` to have automatic storage duration?

I read the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13430831/return-by-rvalue-reference), but the top answer only shows that the spec should not allow moving when passing `a` to other functions in the function body; it does not explain why moving *when returning* is safe for `g` but not for `f`. Once we get to the return statement, we will not need `a` anymore inside `f`.

## Update 0

So I understand that temporaries are accessible until the end of the full expression. However, the behavior when returning from `f` still seems to go against the semantics ingrained into the language that it is safe to move a temporary or an xvalue. For example, if you call `g(A())`, the temporary is moved into the argument for `g` even though there could be references to the temporary stored somewhere. The same happens if we call `g` with an xvalue. Since only temporaries and xvalues bind to rvalue references, it seems like to be consistent about the semantics we should still move `a` when returning from `f`, since we know `a` was passed either a temporary or an xvalue.

Comment: I may be wrong but it almost seems like you answered your own question - "... the spec should not allow moving when passing a to other functions in the function `body` ..." - I would think in the case of `g` it is return value optimization that's allowing it to work. Consider how calls to `f` would look with respect to `a` - there is nothing to say after `f` returns that `a` would continue to exist.

Comment: But once we get to the return statement, there's not risk that we will need the object again inside `f` (or `g`). Also, from what I understand, return value optimization is somewhat orthogonal to whether we perform a move vs. a copy.

Comment: The best way to think of rvalues is how many times you can refer to them with references. If you can't refer to the object by a variable name, it's an rvalue. You can have rvalue variables such as `A && z = ...` but I can't think of a valid reason to do this. The `&&` tells `f` that it should only accept objects that can no longer be referred to, otherwise assume it is exactly like `A f(A & a)` with the same consequences (I tend to anyway). Then it starts to make sense why `f` is likely to copy while `g` wont - `g` creates its own temp object while `f` is copying the "last" reference to it.

Comment: How did you determine this behavior in the first place?

Comment: See http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/258238/move-semantics-in-c-move-return-of-local-variables for an example where the compiler chooses to move, even though it breaks invariants.

Comment: Re the invariant breaking - this is normal. As you change standards, so does the language. Prior to C++11 you _didn't have move constructors_ so it's natural that the cases where _either_ constructor could be used there will be some breaking. Move constructors are expected to _partly destroy the source object_ as it "steals" the data and refers to it in the new object. With only a default move constructor, all class members (assuming they can be) will be moved rather than copied, in C++11. In general if you rely on 'default behavior' you can't assume it will be the same in the next standard.

Answer (score 7):

Second attempt. Hopefully this is more <strike>succinct and</strike> clear.

I am going to ignore RVO almost entirely for this discussion. It makes it really confusing as to what should happen sans optimizations - this is just about move vs copy semantics.

To assist this a reference is going to be very helpful here on [the sorts of value types in c++11](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category).

### When to move?

#### lvalue

These are never moved. They refer to variables or storage locations that are potentially being referred to elsewhere, and as such should not have their contents transferred to another instance.

#### prvalue

The above defines them as "expressions that do not have identity". Clearly nothing else can refer to a nameless value so these can be moved.

#### rvalue

The general case of "right-hand" value, and the only thing that's certain is they can be moved from. They may or may not have a named reference, but if they do it is the last such usage.

#### xvalue

These are sort of a mix of both - they have identity (are a reference) *and* they can be moved from. They need not have a named variable. The reason? They are eXpiring values, about to be destroyed. Consider them the 'final reference'. **xvalues can only be generated from rvalues** which is why/how `std::move` works in converting lvalues to xvalues (through the result of a function call).

#### glvalue

Another mutant type with its rvalue cousin, it can be either an xvalue or an lvalue - it has identity but it's unclear if this is the last reference to the variable / storage or not, hence it is unclear if it can or cannot be moved from.

### Resolution Order

Where an overload exists that can accept either a `const lvalue ref` or `rvalue ref`, and an rvalue is passed, the rvalue is bound otherwise the lvalue version is used. (move for rvalues, copy otherwise).

### Where it potentially happens

(assume all types are `A` where not mentioned)

It only occurs where an object is "initialized from an xvalue of the same type". xvalues bind to rvalues but are not as restricted as pure expressions. In other words, movable things are more than unnamed references, they can also be the 'last' reference to an object with respect to the compiler's awareness.

#### initialization

```
A a = std::move(b); // assign-move
A a( std::move(b) ); // construct-move
```

#### function argument passing

```
void f( A a );
f( std::move(b) );
```

#### function return

```
A f() {
    // A a exists, will discuss shortly
    return a;
}
```

### Why it will not happen in `f`

Consider this variation on f:

```
void action1(A & a) {
    // alter a somehow
}

void action2(A & a) {
    // alter a somehow
}

A f(A && a) {
    action1( a );
    action2( a );
    return a;
}
```

It is not illegal to treat `a` as an lvalue within `f`. Because it is an `lvalue` it must be a reference, whether explicit or not. Every plain-old variable is technically a reference to itself.

That's where we trip up. Because `a` is an lvalue for the purposes of `f`, we are in fact returning an lvalue.

To explicitly generate an rvalue, we must use `std::move` (or generate an `A&&` result some other way).

### Why it will happen in `g`

With that under our belts, consider `g`

```
A g(A a) {
    action1( a ); // as above
    action2( a ); // as above
    return a;
}
```

Yes, `a` is an lvalue for the purposes of `action1` and `action2`. However, because all references to `a` only exist within `g` (it's a copy or moved-into copy), it can be considered an xvalue in the return.

### But why not in `f`?

There is no specific magic to `&&`. Really, you should think of it as a reference first and foremost. The fact that we are demanding an rvalue *reference* in `f` as opposed to an lvalue *reference* with `A&` does not alter the fact that, being a reference, it must be an lvalue, because the *storage location* of `a` is external to `f` and that's as far as any compiler will be concerned.

The same does not apply in `g`, where it's clear that `a`'s storage is temporary and exists only when `g` is called and at no other time. In this case it is clearly an xvalue and can be moved.

---

### `rvalue ref` vs `lvalue ref` and safety of reference passing

Suppose we overload a function to accept both types of references. What would happen?

```
void v( A  & lref );
void v( A && rref );
```

The only time `void v( A&& )` will be used per the above ("Where it potentially happens"), otherwise `void v( A& )`. That is, an rvalue ref will always attempt to bind to an rvalue ref signature before an lvalue ref overload is attempted. An lvalue ref should not ever bind to the rvalue ref except in the case where it can be treated as an xvalue (guaranteed to be destroyed in the current scope whether we want it to or not).

It is tempting to say that in the rvalue case we know for sure that the object being passed is temporary. That is not the case. It is a signature *intended for* binding references to what *appears to be* a temporary object.

For analogy, it's like doing `int * x = 23;` - it may be wrong, but you could (eventually) force it to compile with bad results if you run it. The compiler can't say for sure if you're being serious about that or pulling its leg.

With respect to safety one must consider functions that do this (and why not to do this - if it still compiles at all):

```
A & make_A(void) {
    A new_a;
    return new_a;
}
```

While there is nothing ostensibly wrong with the language aspect - the types work and we will get a reference to *somewhere* back - because `new_a`'s storage location is *inside* a function, the memory will be reclaimed / invalid when the function returns. Therefore anything that uses the result of this function will be dealing with freed memory.

Similarly, `A f( A && a )` is intended to but is not limited to accepting prvalues or xvalues if we really want to force something else through. That's where `std::move` comes in, and let's us do just that.

The reason this is the case is because it differs from `A f( A & a )` **only with respect to which contexts it will be preferred, over the rvalue overload**. In all other respects it is identical in how `a` is treated by the compiler.

The fact that we *know* that `A&&` is a signature reserved for moves is a moot point; it is used to determine which version of "reference to `A` -type parameter" we want to bind to, the sort where we *should* take ownership (rvalue) or the sort where we *should not* take ownership (lvalue) of the underlying data (that is, move it elsewhere and wipe the instance / reference we're given). In both cases, what we are working with is a *reference to memory that is not controlled by `f`*.

Whether we do or not is not something the compiler can tell; it falls into the 'common sense' area of programming, such as not to use memory locations that don't make sense to use but are otherwise valid memory locations.

What the compiler knows about `A f( A && a )` is to not create new storage for `a`, since we're going to be given an address (reference) to work with. We can choose to leave the source address untouched, but the whole idea here is that by declaring `A&&` we're telling the compiler "hey! give me references to objects that are about to disappear so I might be able to do something with it before that happens". The key word here is *might*, and again also the fact that we can explicitly target this function signature incorrectly.

Consider if we had a version of `A` that, when move-constructing, did not erase the old instance's data, and for some reason we did this by design (let's say we had our own memory allocation functions and knew exactly how our memory model would keep data beyond the lifetime of objects).

The compiler cannot know this, because it would take code analysis to determine what happens to the objects when they're handled in rvalue bindings - it's a human judgement issue at that point. At best the compiler sees 'a reference, yay, no allocating extra memory here' and follows rules of reference passing.

It's safe to assume the compiler is thinking: "it's a reference, I don't need to deal with its memory lifetime inside `f`, it being a temporary will be removed after `f` is finished".

In that case, when a temporary is passed to `f`, the storage of that temporary will disappear as soon as we leave `f`, and then we're potentially in the same situation as `A & make_A(void)` - a very bad one.

### An issue of semantics...

#### `std::move`

The very purpose of `std::move` is to create rvalue references. By and large what it does (if nothing else) is force the resulting value to bind to rvalues as opposed to lvalues. The reason for this is a return signature of `A&` prior to rvalue references being available, was ambiguous for things like operator overloads (and other uses surely).

#### Operators - an example

```
class A {
    // ...
  public:
    A & operator= (A & rhs); // what is the lifetime of rhs? move or copy intended?
    A & operator+ (A & rhs); // ditto
    // ...
};

int main() {
    A result = A() + A(); // wont compile!
}
```

Note that this *will not accept temporary objects for either operator*! Nor does it make sense to do this in the case of object copy operations - why do we need to modify an original object that we are *copying*, probably *in order to* have a copy we can modify later. This is the reason we have to declare `const A &` parameters for copy operators and any situation where a copy is to be taken of the reference, as a guarantee that we are not altering the original object.

Naturally this is an issue with moves, where we *must* modify the original object to avoid the new container's data being freed prematurely. (hence "move" operation).

To solve this mess along comes `T&&` declarations, which are a replacement to the above example code, and specifically target references to objects in the situations where the above won't compile. But, we wouldn't need to modify `operator+` to be a move operation, and you'd be hard pressed to find a reason for doing so (though you could I think). Again, because of the assumption that addition should not modify the original object, only the left-operand object in the expression. So we can do this:

```
class A {
    // ...
  public:
    A & operator= (const A & rhs); // copy-assign
    A & operator= (A && rhs); // move-assign
    A & operator+ (const A & rhs); // don't modify rhs operand
    // ...
};

int main() {
    A result = A() + A(); // const A& in addition, and A&& for assign
    A result2 = A().operator+(A()); // literally the same thing
}
```

What you should take note of here is that *despite* the fact that `A()` returns a temporary, it not only is able to bind to `const A&` but it *should* because of the expected semantics of addition (that it does not modify its right operand). The second version of the assignment is clearer why only one of the arguments should be expected to be modified.

It's also clear that a move will occur on the assignment, and no move will occur with `rhs` in `operator+`.

#### Separation of return value semantics and argument binding semantics

The reason that there is only one move above is clear from the function (well, operator) definitions. What's important is we are indeed binding what is clearly an xvalue / rvalue, to what is unmistakably an lvalue in `operator+`.

I have to stress this point: there is no effective difference in this example in the way that `operator+` and `operator=` refer to their argument. As far as the compiler is concerned, within either's function body the argument is effectively `const A&` for `+` and `A&` for `=`. The difference is purely in `const`ness. The only way in which `A&` and `A&&` differ is to distinguish signatures, not types.

With different signatures come different semantics, it's the compiler's toolkit for distinguishing certain cases where there otherwise is no clear distinction from the code. The behavior of the functions themselves - the code body - may not be able to tell the cases apart either!

Another example of this is `operator++(void)` vs `operator++(int)`. The former expects to return its underlying value *before* an increment operation and the latter afterwards. There is no `int` being passed, it's just so the compiler has two signatures to work with - there is just no other way to specify two identical functions with the same name, and as you may or may not know, it is illegal to overload a function on just the return type for similar reasons of ambiguity.

### rvalue variables and other odd situations - an exhaustive test

To understand unambiguously what is happening in `f` I've put together a smorgasbord of things one "should not attempt but look like they'd work" that forces the compiler's hand on the matter almost exhaustively:

```
void bad (int && x, int && y) {
  x += y;
}
int & worse (int && z) {
  return z++, z + 1, 1 + z;
}
int && justno (int & no) {
  return worse( no );
}
int num () {
  return 1;
}
int main () {
  int && a = num();
  ++a = 0;
  a++ = 0;
  bad( a, a );
  int && b = worse( a );
  int && c = justno( b );
  ++c = (int) 'y';
  c++ = (int) 'y';
  return 0;
}
```

`g++ -std=gnu++11 -O0 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -o "src\\basictest.o" "..\\src\\basictest.cpp"`

```
..\src\basictest.cpp: In function 'int& worse(int&&)':
..\src\basictest.cpp:5:17: warning: right operand of comma operator has no effect [-Wunused-value]
   return z++, z + 1, 1 + z;
                 ^
..\src\basictest.cpp:5:26: error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'int&' from an rvalue of type 'int'
   return z++, z + 1, 1 + z;
                          ^
..\src\basictest.cpp: In function 'int&& justno(int&)':
..\src\basictest.cpp:8:20: error: cannot bind 'int' lvalue to 'int&&'
   return worse( no );
                    ^
..\src\basictest.cpp:4:7: error:   initializing argument 1 of 'int& worse(int&&)'
 int & worse (int && z) {
       ^
..\src\basictest.cpp: In function 'int main()':
..\src\basictest.cpp:16:13: error: cannot bind 'int' lvalue to 'int&&'
   bad( a, a );
             ^
..\src\basictest.cpp:1:6: error:   initializing argument 1 of 'void bad(int&&, int&&)'
 void bad (int && x, int && y) {
      ^
..\src\basictest.cpp:17:23: error: cannot bind 'int' lvalue to 'int&&'
   int && b = worse( a );
                       ^
..\src\basictest.cpp:4:7: error:   initializing argument 1 of 'int& worse(int&&)'
 int & worse (int && z) {
       ^
..\src\basictest.cpp:21:7: error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment
   c++ = (int) 'y';
       ^
..\src\basictest.cpp: In function 'int& worse(int&&)':
..\src\basictest.cpp:6:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
 }
 ^
..\src\basictest.cpp: In function 'int&& justno(int&)':
..\src\basictest.cpp:9:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
 }
 ^

01:31:46 Build Finished (took 72ms)
```

This is the unaltered output sans build header which you don't need to see :) I will leave it as an exercise to understand the errors found but re-reading my own explanations (particularly in what follows) it should be apparent what each error was caused by and why, imo anyway.

### Conclusion - What can we learn from this?

First, note that the compiler treats function bodies as individual code units. This is basically the key here. Whatever the compiler does with a function body, it cannot make assumptions about the behavior of the function that would require the function body to be altered. To deal with those cases there are *templates* but that's beyond the scope of this discussion - just note that templates generate multiple function bodies to handle different cases, while otherwise the same function body must be re-usable in every case the function could be used.

Second, rvalue types were predominantly envisioned for move operations - a very specific circumstance that was expected to occur in assignment and construction of objects. Other semantics using rvalue reference bindings are beyond the scope of any compiler to deal with. In other words, it's better to think of rvalue references as syntax sugar than actual code. The signature differs in `A&&` vs `A&` but the argument type for the purposes of the function body does not, it is always treated as `A&` with the *intention* that the object being passed *should* be modified in some way because `const A&`, while correct syntactically, would not allow the desired behavior.

I can be very sure at this point when I say that the compiler will generate the code body for `f` as if it were declared `f(A&)`. Per above, `A&&` assists the compiler in choosing when to *allow* binding a mutable reference to `f` but otherwise the compiler doesn't consider the semantics of `f(A&)` and `f(A&&)` to be different with respect to what `f` *returns*.

It's a long way of saying: the return method of `f` does not depend on the type of argument it receives.

The confusion is elision. In reality there are two copies in the returning of a value. First a copy is created as a temporary, then this temporary is assigned to something (or it isn't and remains purely temporary). The *second* copy is very likely elided via return optimization. The *first* copy can be moved in `g` and cannot in `f`. I expect in a situation where `f` cannot be elided, there will be a copy then a move from `f` in the original code.

To override this the temporary must be explicitly constructed using `std::move`, that is, in the return statement in `f`. However in `g` we're returning something that is known to be temporary to the function body of `g`, hence it is either moved twice, or moved once then elided.

I would suggest compiling the original code with all optimizations disabled and adding in diagnostic messages to copy and move constructors to keep tabs on when and where the values are moved or copied before elision becomes a factor. Even if I'm mistaken, an un-optimized trace of the constructors / operations used would paint an unambiguous picture of what the compiler has done, hopefully it will be apparent why it did what it did as well...

Comment: In short, you want to say in `f(A && a) ` "**a**" is a type of reference (i.e `lvalue`) and therefore it has an identity outside function `f` and therefore its not a temporary object while returning from function `f` and therefore it cannot be utilized in move semantics.

Comment: @sameerkn yes, exactly.

Comment: I completely forgot an example of when assuming `f` will return by move will be a bad assumption. In any case the remedy would be to explicitly define `f` as `A && f(A && a);` which should trigger implicit conversion on return. If the idea is to do work with a temporary and pass it along as a temporary, that would indeed be the signature of such a function, imo. Caution must be taken with such a function, I don't advise to use such things until you're really, really, really sure you know when and how it'll be used. And even then.

Comment: Have one doubt. Consider this: `function f(A && a);  A aa; f(aa);`   now will `aa` be passed as a simple reference as in  `f(A & a);`. OR  Are `f(A && a);` and `g(A & a)` same? So whenever an object is tried to pass to `f` or `g` then it will always be passed just as a reference?

Comment: I still don't understand why it's not safe to move `a` when returning from `f`. By its signature, we know that it can only be passed either a prvalue (which you suggest is clearly moveable) or an xvalue (which, since it is conceptually an expiring value, should also be safely moveable).

Comment: I've updated my answer to address these things as best I can, hopefully it makes sense. Very briefly it comes down to "the compiler doesn't read into how we use references, just where the original memory location is and when *that* is cleaned up". `f` is using a temporary that exists for longer than the call but shorter than the following outer statement, so moving it may end up referring to freed memory without some guarantee. The compiler doesn't have one, so any forwarding of rvalues in this case has to be explicit.

Comment: I've updated my question to ask about consistent semantics. In particular, if you use pathological move constructors, then you'll have exactly the same kinds of problems when you pass temporaries or xvalues to `g`, since `g` performs a move when it is passed an argument. In both cases (returning from `f` or passing the argument into `g`) the move isn't technically safe, but if we assume proper semantics, then it is. So why does one of them become a move and the other a copy?

Comment: Regarding object lifecycle, when you move an object, the original object is not freed right away; it must be left in a (somewhat) valid state, because the destructor will be called on it at the end of the full-expression. So the compiler wouldn't need to have super-compiler knowledge to move `a` in `f`. It would just need to move it as if you had used `std::move` (after checking whether the move constructor is usable).

Comment: Also, you wrote, "`A f( A && a )` is intended to but is not limited to accepting prvalues or xvalues if we really want to force something else through. That's where `std::move` comes in," but `std::move` is actually no exception--it yields an xvalue. When you use it, you are explicitly marking something as safe-to-be-moved.

Comment: @JeremyB. I've updated my answer, addressing the semantics of the issue. hopefully that covers everything about this situation, please let me know if anything else should be added / clarified :)

Comment: Thanks for the update. You make the point that a compiler would treat lvalue and rvalue reference parameters the same once inside the function since they're implemented the same. Why does the latter have to imply the former? For example, a `const A &` and an `A &` parameter would both be implemented the same, but the compiler would still apply overload resolution once inside the function. Why can't we do something similar here?

Comment: @JeremyB. no probs. Because the compiler does not use overload resolution _once inside_ the function, only from the outside, because it forms `f` and `g` (or any function) in a way as to have the code re-usable, without knowing ahead of time which context the function will be used in (to cater for all cases at once). I've tested this yesterday: an `A&&` value cannot bind to `const A &` but can to `A &&` or `A &` (it will overload in that order), and second, ignoring `const`ness in all three types of binding the local reference itself is `A &`.

Comment: I did this: `#define make_detector(name, type) void name(type x){cout<<"("<<#type<<") detected"<<endl;}` and then `make_detector( detector, int & )` `make_detector( detector, int && )` `make_detector( detector, const int & )` - then with `void f (int && a ) { detector( a ); }` I got: `(int &) detected`

Comment: To put it another way, we have three reference-type overloads possible. One where we make no promises about what we could do with the value or what sort of context it's obtained in (`A &`), one where we promise not to modify the value (`const A &`), and one where we _expect_ not to see the value again and _should_ modify (`A &&`). `const A &&` would not work: if an rvalue can bind to `A &` and `A &&` but not `const A &`, it won't bind to `const A &&` for the same reason it will fail to bind to `const A &`, since `A &` is an allowable fallback to `A &&` (issue is `const`).

Comment: Nope... lol disregard that last part. Not _fail to bind to_ - _can but I don't see why you would need to_ is more apt. Just tested, and `const int &&` does indeed bind to become `const int &`. If that has a use, go for it. I can't think of one at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Short story: it only depends on `doSomething`.

Medium story: if `doSomething` **never** change `a`, then `f` is safe. It receives a rvalue reference and returns a new temporary moved from there.

Long story: things will go bad as soon as `doSomething` uses `a` in a move operation, because a may be in an undefined state before it is used in the return statement - it would be the same in `g` but at least the conversion to a rvalue reference should be explicit

TL/DR: both `f` and `g` are safe as long as there is no move operation inside `doSomething`. The difference comes that a move will silently executed in `f`, while it will require an explicit conversion to a rvalue reference (eg with `std::move`) in g.

Comment: What about [this point](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category#lvalue) - "The following expressions are lvalue expressions: ... the name of a variable or a function in scope, _regardless of type_, such as std::cin or std::endl. _Even if the variable's type is rvalue reference_, the expression consisting of its name is an lvalue expression; " (emphasis added). In that case wouldn't `doSomething` have no effect on whether a move occurs in `f` when returning `a`?

Comment: @XerenNarcy: I did some tests using Clang, and I can confirm that if `doSomething` moves `a`, the function returns a copy of an object that was already in a undeterminated state - In my tests, I moved an object containing a std::string, and the object that received the result of the function had lost the string content.

Comment: That's true, that is the result I would expect from such a case. But what if doSomething just accepted an rvalue and didn't actually move the string? eg, `void doSomething(std::string&&a){return;}`? I can argue against semantics as the cause and that it's an optimization, because you can nest doSomething with an identical but differently named function, perhaps in pre-compiled code, that behaves identically to this example `doSomething(std::string&&)` but without the compiler being aware of it. Turtles all the way down, etc..

Comment: To be precise, what happens in an example where `doSomething(std::string&&)` _does_ perform a move: the outer function still returns `a` in the same sense in that the same container object is referred to whether or not `doSomething` alters the contents. The actual result - the contents of the returned container, whether it is copied or moved from that point onwards - will be empty if and only if `doSomething` modifies it, but that doesn't change the method of transport for `a`'s data in and out of `f`.

Comment: @XerenNarcy: if `doSomething` takes a `A` or a `const & A` as parameter, the original `a` in f will not be changed. But if it takes a *reference* to a, it will change the value of the original variable referenced from f, so not only it will be undeterminated in caller, but also in f, since both share the same actual variable. At the time when f returns, `a` may have lost its values.

Comment: I agree, that's not what I'm nitpicking over though - it's this (emphasis added): "But if it takes a reference to a, it _will_ change the value ... ". There is no such guarantee and in fact there doesn't need to be, [see here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move#Notes): "The functions that accept rvalue reference parameters ... If the argument identifies a resource-owning object, these overloads have the option, **but aren't required**, to move any resources held by the argument." (emphasis mine again)

Answer (score 0):

Third attempt. The second became very long in the process of explaining every nook and cranny of the situation. But hey, I learned a lot too in the process, which I suppose is the point, no? :) Anyway. I'll re-address the question anew, keeping my longer answer as it in itself is a useful reference but falls short of a 'clear explanation'.

## What are we dealing with here?

`f` and `g` are not trivial situations. They take time to understand and appreciate the first few times you encounter them. The issues at play are the **lifetime of objects**, **Return Value Optimization**, confusion of **returning object values**, and confusion with **overloads of reference types**. I'll address each and explain their relevance.

### References

First thing's first. What's a reference? Aren't they just pointers without the syntax?

They are, but in an important way they're much more than that. Pointers are literally that, they refer to memory locations in general. There are few if any guarantees about the values located at wherever the pointer is set to. References on the other hand are bound to addresses of real values - values that guarantee to exist *for the duration they can be accessed*, but may not have a name for them available to be accessed in any other way (such as temporaries).

As a rule of thumb, if you can 'take its address' then you're dealing with a reference, a rather special one known as an `lvalue`. You can assign to an lvalue. This is why `*pointer = 3` works, the operator `*` creates a reference to the address being pointed to.

This doesn't make the reference any more or less valid than the address it points to, however, references you *naturally find* in C++ do have this guarantee (as would well-written C++ code) - that they are referring to real values in a way where we don't need to know about its lifetime for the duration of our interactions with them.

### Lifetime of Objects

We all should know by now when the c'tors and d'tors will be called for something like this:

```
{
  A temp;
  temp.property = value;
}
```

`temp`'s scope is set. We know exactly when it's created and destroyed. One way we can be sure it's destroyed is because this is impossible:

```
A & ref_to_temp = temp; // nope
A * ptr_to_temp = &temp; // double nope
```

The compiler stops us from doing that because *very* clearly we should not expect that object to still exist. This can arise *subtly* whenever using references, which is why sometimes people can be found suggesting avoidance of references until you know what you're doing with them (or entirely if they've given up understanding them and just want to move on with their lives).

### Scope of Expressions

On the other hand we also have to be mindful that temporaries exist until the outer-most expression they're found in has completed. That means up to the semicolon. An expression existing in the LHS of a comma operator, for example, doesn't get destroyed until the semicolon. Ie:

```
struct scopetester {
    static int counter = 0;
    scopetester(){++counter;}
    ~scopetester(){--counter;}
};

scopetester(), std::cout << scopetester::counter; // prints 1
scopetester(), scopetester(), std::cout << scopetester::counter; // prints 2
```

This still does not avoid issues of sequencing of execution, you still have to deal with `++i++` and other things - operator precedence and the dreaded *undefined behavior* that can result when forcing ambiguous cases (eg `i++ = ++i`). What is important is that all temporaries created exist until the semicolon and no longer.

There are two exceptions - *elision / in-place-construction* (aka RVO) and *reference-assignment-from-temporary*.

### Returning by value and Elision

What is elision? Why use RVO and similar things? All of these come down under a single term that's far easier to appreciate - "in-place construction". Suppose we were using the result of a function call to initialize or set an object. Eg:

```
A x (void) {return A();}
A y( x() );
```

Lets consider the longest possible sequence of events that could happen here.

1. A new `A` is constructed in `x`
2. The temporary value returned by `x()` is a new `A`, initialized using a reference to the previous
3. A new `A` - `y` - is initialized using the temporary value

Where possible, the compiler should re-arrange things so that as few as possible intermediate `A`'s are constructed where it's *safe to assume* the intermediate is inaccessible or otherwise unnecessary. The question is *which* of the objects can we do without?

Case #1 is an explicit new object. If we are to avoid this being created, we need to have a reference to an object that already exists. This is the most straightforward one and nothing more needs to be said.

In #2 we cannot avoid constructing *some* result. After all, we are returning *by value*. However, there are two important exceptions (not including exceptions themselves which are *also* affected when thrown): **NRVO** and **RVO**. These affect what happens in #3, but there are important consequences and *rules* regarding #2...

This is due to an interesting [quirk of elision](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision#Notes):

> **Notes**
>
> Copy elision is the only allowed form of optimization that can change the observable side-effects. Because some compilers do not perform copy elision in every situation where it is allowed (e.g., in debug mode), programs that rely on the side-effects of copy/move constructors and destructors are not portable.
>
> Even when copy elision takes place and the copy-/move-constructor is not called, it must be present and accessible (as if no optimization happened at all), otherwise the program is ill-formed.
>
> *(Since C++11)*
>
> In a return statement or a throw-expression, if the compiler cannot perform copy elision but the conditions for copy elision are met or would be met, except that the source is a function parameter, the compiler will attempt to use the move constructor even if the object is designated by an lvalue; see return statement for details.

And more on that in the [return statement notes](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/return#Notes):

> **Notes**
>
> Returning by value may involve construction and copy/move of a temporary object, unless copy elision is used.
>
> *(Since C++11)*
>
> If `expression` is an lvalue expression and the conditions for copy elision are met, or would be met, except that `expression` names a function parameter, then overload resolution to select the constructor to use for initialization of the returned value is performed twice: first as if `expression` were an rvalue expression (thus it may select the move constructor or a copy constructor taking reference to const), and if no suitable conversion is available, overload resolution is performed the second time, with lvalue expression (so it may select the copy constructor taking a reference to non-const).
>
> The above rule applies even if the function return type is different from the type of `expression` (copy elision requires same type)

The compiler is allowed to even chain together multiple elisions. All it means is that two sides of a move / copy that would involve an intermediate object, could potentially be made to refer directly to each-other or even be made to be the same object. We don't know and *shouldn't need to know* when the compiler chooses to do this - it's an optimization, for one, but importantly you should think of move and copy constructors et al as a "last resort" usage.

We can agree the goal is to reduce the number of unnecessary operations in any optimization, provided the observable behavior is the same. Move and copy constructors are used *wherever moves and copy operations happen*, so what about when the compiler sees fit to remove a move/copy operation itself as an optimization? Should the *functionally unnecessary* intermediate objects exist in the final program just for the purposes of their side effects? The way the standard is right now, and compilers, seems to be: no - the move and copy constructors satisfy the *how* of those operations, not the *when* or *why*.

The short version: You have less temporary objects, that you ought to not care about to begin with, so why should you miss them. If you do miss them it may just be that your code relies on intermediate copies and moves to do things beyond their stated purpose and contexts.

Lastly, you need to be aware that the elided object is *always* stored (and constructed) in the *receiving* location, not the location of its inception.

Quoting [this reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) -

> **Named Return Value Optimization**
>
> If a function returns a class type by value, and the return statement's expression is the name of a non-volatile object with automatic storage duration, which isn't the function parameter, or a catch clause parameter, and which has the same type (ignoring top-level cv-qualification) as the return type of the function, then copy/move is omitted. When that local object is constructed, it is constructed directly in the storage where the function's return value would otherwise be moved or copied to. This variant of copy elision is known as NRVO, "named return value optimization".
>
> **Return Value Optimization**
>
> When a nameless temporary, not bound to any references, would be moved or copied into an object of the same type (ignoring top-level cv-qualification), the copy/move is omitted. When that temporary is constructed, it is constructed directly in the storage where it would otherwise be moved or copied to. When the nameless temporary is the argument of a return statement, this variant of copy elision is known as RVO, "return value optimization".

### Lifetime of References

One thing we should not do, is this:

```
A & func() {
    A result;
    return result;
}
```

While tempting because it would avoid implicit copying of anything (we're just passing an address right?) it's also a short-sighted approach. Remember the compiler above preventing something looking like this with `temp`? Same thing here - `result` is gone once we're done with `func`, it could be reclaimed and could be anything now.

The reason we cannot is because we cannot pass an address to `result` out of `func` - whether as reference or as pointer - and consider it valid memory. We would get no further passing `A*` out.

In this situation it is best to use an object-copy return type and rely on moves, elision or both to occur as the compiler finds suitable. Always think of copy and move constructors as 'measures of last resort' - you should not rely on the compiler to use them because the compiler *can* find ways to avoid copy and move operations entirely, and is *allowed to* do so even if it means the side effects of those constructors wouldn't happen any more.

There is however a special case, alluded to earlier.

Recall that references are *guarantees* to real values. This implies that the *first* occurrence of the reference initializes the object and the *last* (as far as known at compile time) destroys it when going out of scope.

Broadly this covers two situations: when we return a temporary *from* a function. and when we *assign* from a function result. The first, returning a temporary, is basically what elision does but you can in effect elide explicitly with reference passing - like passing a pointer in a call chain. It constructs the object at the time of return, but what changes is the object is no longer destroyed after leaving scope (the return statement). And on the other end the second kind happens - the variable storing the result of the function call now has the honor of destroying the value when *it* goes out of scope.

The important point here is that elision and reference passing are related concepts. You can emulate elision by using pointers to uninitialized variables' storage location (of known type), for example, as you can with reference passing semantics (basically what they're *for*).

### Overloads of Reference Types

References allow us to treat non-local variables as if they are local variables - to take their address, write to that address, read from that address, and importantly, be able to destroy the object at the right time - when the address can no longer be reached by anything.

Regular variables when they leave scope, have their only reference to them disappear, and are promptly destroyed at that time. Reference variables can refer to regular variables, but except for elision / RVO circumstances they do not affect the scope of the original object - not even if the object they referred to goes out of scope early, which can happen if you make references to dynamic memory and are not careful to manage those references yourself.

This means you can capture the results of an expression explicitly by reference. How? Well, this may seem odd at first but if you read the above it will make sense why this works:

```
class A {
    /* assume rule-of-5 (inc const-overloads) has been followed but unless
     * otherwise noted the members are private */
  public:
    A (void) { /* ... */ }
    A operator+ ( const A & rhs ) {
        A res;
        // do something with `res`
        return res;
    }
};

A x = A() + A(); // doesn't compile
A & y = A() + A(); // doesn't compile
A && z = A() + A(); // compiles
```

#### Why? What's going on?

`A x = ...` - we can't because constructors and assignment is private.

`A & y = ...` - we can't because we're returning a value, not a reference to a value who's scope is greater or equal to our current scope.

`A && z = ...` - we can because we're able to refer to xvalues. As consequence of this assignment the lifetime of the temporary value is extended to this capturing lvalue because it in effect has become an lvalue reference. Sound familiar? It's *explicit elision* if I were to call it anything. This is more apparent when you consider this syntax must involve a new value and must involve assigning that value to a reference.

In all three cases when all constructors and assignment is made public, there is always only three objects constructed, with the address of `res` always matching the variable storing the result. (on my compiler anyway, optimizations disabled, -std=gnu++11, g++ 4.9.3).

Which means the differences really do come down to just the storage duration of function arguments themselves. Elision and move operations cannot happen on anything but pure expressions, expiring values, or explicit targeting of the "expiring values" reference overload `Type&&`.

### Re-examining `f` and `g`

I've annotated the situation in both functions to get things rolling, a shortlist of assumptions the compiler would note when generating (reusable) code for each.

```
A f( A && a ) {
    // has storage duration exceeding f's scope.
    // already constructed.

    return a;
    // can be elided.
    // must be copy-constructed, a exceeds f's scope.
}

A g( A a ) {
    // has storage duration limited to this function's scope.
    // was just constructed somehow, whether by elision, move or copy.

    return a;
    // elision may occur.
    // can move-construct if can't elide.
    // can copy-construct if can't move.
}
```

What we can say for sure about `f`'s `a` is that it's expecting to capture moved or expression-type values. Because `f` can accept either expression-references (prvalues) or lvalue-references about to disappear (xvalues) or moved lvalue-references (converted to xvalues via `std::move`), and because `f` must be homogenous in the treatment of `a` for all three cases, `a` is seen as a reference first and foremost to an area of memory who's lifetime exists for longer than a call to `f`. That is, it is not possible to distinguish which of the three cases we called `f` with from within `f`, so the compiler assumes the longest storage duration it needs for any of the cases, and finds it safest not to assume anything about the storage duration of `a`'s data.

Unlike the situation in `g`. Here, `a` - however it happens upon its value - will cease to be accessible beyond a call to `g`. As such returning it is tantamount to moving it, since it's seen as an xvalue in that case. We could still copy it or more probably even elide it, it can depend on which is allowed / defined for `A` at the time.

#### The issues with `f`

```
// we can't tell these apart.
// `f` when compiled cannot assume either will always happen.
// case-by-case optimizations can only happen if `f` is
// inlined into the final code and then re-arranged, or if `f`
// is made into a template to specifically behave differently
// against differing types.

A case_1() {
    // prvalues
    return f( A() + A() );
}

A make_case_2() {
    // xvalues
    A temp;
    return temp;
}
A case_2 = f( make_case_2() )

A case_3(A & other) {
    // lvalues
    return f( std::move( other ) );
}
```

Because of the ambiguity of usage the compiler and standards are designed to make `f` usable consistently in all cases. There can be no assumptions that `A&&` will always be a new expression or that you will only use it with `std::move` for its argument etc. Once `f` is made external to your code, leaving only its call signature, that cannot be the excuse anymore. The function signature - which reference overload to target - is a clue to what the function should be doing with it and how much (or little) it can assume about the context.

rvalue references are not a panacea for targeting only "moved values", they can target a good deal more things and even be targeted incorrectly or unexpectedly if you assume that's all they do. A reference to *anything* in general should be expected to and be made to exist for longer than the reference does, with the one exception being rvalue reference variables.

rvalue reference variables are in essence, *elision operators*. Wherever they exist there is in-place construction going on of some description.

As regular variables, they extend the scope of any xvalue or rvalue they receive - they hold the result of the expression as it's constructed rather than by move or copy, and from thereon are equivalent to regular reference variables in usage.

As function variables they can also elide and construct objects in-place, but there is a very important difference between this:

```
A c = f( A() );
```

and this:

```
A && r = f( A() );
```

The difference is there is no guarantee that `c` will be move-constructed vs elided, but `r` definitely will be elided / constructed in-place at some point, owing to the nature of what we're binding *to*. For this reason we can only assign to `r` in situations where there will be a new temporary value created.

### But why is `A&&a` not destroyed if it is captured?

Consider this:

```
void bad_free(A && a) {
    A && clever = std::move( a );
    // 'clever' should be the last reference to a?
}
```

This won't work. The reason is subtle. `a`'s scope is longer, and rvalue reference assignments can only *extend* the lifetime, not control it. `clever` exists for less time than `a`, and therefore is not an xvalue itself (unless using `std::move` again, but then you're back to the same situation, and it continues forth etc).

#### lifetime extension

Remember that what makes lvalues different to rvalues is that they cannot be bound to objects that have less lifetime than themselves. All lvalue references are either the original variable or a reference that has less lifetime than the original.

rvalues allow binding to reference variables that have *longer* lifetime than the original value - that's half the point. Consider:

```
A r = f( A() ); // v1
A && s = f( A() ); // v2
```

What happens? In both cases `f` is given a temporary value that outlives the call, and a result object (because `f` returns by value) is constructed *somehow* (it will not matter as you shall see). In v1 we are constructing a new object `r` using the temporary result - we can do this in three ways: move, copy, elide. In v2 we are not constructing a new object, we are extending the lifetime of the result of `f` to the scope of `s`, alternatively saying the same: `s` is constructed in-place using `f` and therefore the temporary returned by `f` has its lifetime extended rather than being moved or copied.

The main distinction is v1 **requires** move and copy constructors (at least one) to be defined *even if* the process is elided. For v2 you are not invoking constructors and are explicitly saying you want to reference and/or extend the lifetime of a temporary value, and *because* you don't invoke move or copy constructors the compiler can *only* elide / construct in-place!

Remember that this has nothing to do with the argument given to `f`. It works identically with `g`:

```
A r = g( A() ); // v1
A && s = g( A() ); // v2
```

`g` will create a temporary for its argument and move-construct it using `A()` for both cases. It like `f` also constructs a temporary for its return value, but it can use an xvalue because the result is constructed using a temporary (temporary to `g`). Again, this will not matter because in v1 we have a new object that could be copy-constructed or move-constructed (either is required but not both) while in v2 we are demanding reference to something that's constructed but will disappear if we don't catch it.

#### Explicit xvalue capture

Example to show this is possible in theory (but useless):

```
A && x (void) { 
    A temp;
    // return temp; // even though xvalue, can't do this
    return std::move(temp);
}
A && y = x(); // y now refers to temp, which is destroyed
```

Which object does `y` refer to? We have left the compiler no choice: `y` must refer to the result of some function or expression, and we've given it `temp` which works based on type. But no move has occurred, and `temp` will be deallocated by the time we use it via `y`.

Why didn't lifetime extension kick in for `temp` like it did for `a` in `g` / `f`? Because of what we're returning: we can't specify a function to construct things in-place, we can specify a variable to *be* constructed in place. It also goes to show that the compiler does not look across function / call boundaries to determine lifetime, it will just look at which variables are on the calling side or local, how they're assigned to and how they're initialized if local.

If you want to clear all doubts, try passing this as an rvalue reference: `std::move(*(new A))` - what should happen is that nothing should ever destroy it, because it isn't on the stack and because rvalue references do not alter the lifetime of anything but temporary objects (ie, intermediates / expressions). xvalues are candidates for move construction / move assignment and can't be elided (already constructed) but all other move / copy operations can in theory be elided on the whim of the compiler; when using rvalue references the compiler has no choice but to elide or pass on the address.

Comment: It seems to me that in all three cases you show, the move when returning from `f` would be preferred. In `case_1` and `case_2` we pass in a temporary that nothing else has a reference to (it would seem), and in `case_3` the user explicitly uses `std::move`, implying that we are free to move the object.

Comment: Also, binding to rvalue references does not extend the lifetime of xvalues.

Comment: Those three cases are not about what `f` returns, it's about what `f` receives, to show the ambiguity with compiled / generate-once code and rvalue reference types - `f`'s argument, despite being an rvalue type, can be bound to by expressions, xvalues and explicit casts to rvalue reference. I need to stress that move semantics _rely on_ rvalue references but rvalue references themselves do not suggest moves. For that reason it can bind its argument in all 3 cases, but we can't assume for all 3 that `f` definitely should be able to move its argument (forward data ownership) in the result.

Comment: @JeremyB. I've updated my answer - you're right, xvalues can't be extended. I had in mind the temporary being returned by a function call, however it _is_ possible to return an xvalue by reference (even though it is pointless because the value would be freed by then).

Comment: Can you explain more what you mean when you say, "...move semantics _rely on_ rvalue references but rvalue references themselves do not suggest moves"? I understand that there's ambiguity regarding the scenario that caused an rvalue, but it seems like in all three scenarios, move semantics would be expected.

Comment: @JeremyB. have a look at `bad_free` for a start, nothing but rvalues yet no moves. [Live example](https://ideone.com/7VMU1t) showing that `bad_free` will not perform moves and neither will `std::move` on its own - both just cast to `A&&` what would otherwise be `A&`. It isn't correct to think of rvalues as triggers for moves - rvalues tell the compiler we want to _refer to a temporary rather than copy it_ (hence lifetime extension of rvalues and not xvalues). If there is a barrier to doing so (pass-by-val) then a move is a _less costly compromise_ as otherwise a copy _will_ be required.

Comment: I see. Well, I realize creating an rvalue doesn't guarantee that a move will happen, but I can't think of a reasonable scenario where someone would create an rvalue without the intention of the object being moveable (safe-to-move).

Comment: @JeremyB. There are a few but they boil down to the ability to "capture" temporaries (the one thing normal references can't do). Suppose we _didn't_ want copy or move construction - a guarantee of copy-elision - how would you do it? Because of `f` and `g` differences the compiler can't always do it (but it can even for `f` with `gcc -O3` in theory as it allows inlining to happen). The way to do it is the declaration of the result: `A && a = ...` will in effect construct the result in-place without moves, while `A a = ...` may / may not depending on the expression and optimization level.

Comment: @JeremyB. [another live example](https://ideone.com/FvL78R) showing that, while the return method _seems_ the same for value and rvalue-ref, the addresses used are clearly different - for rvalues the compiler seems to be aware to construct them in another area relative to move-constructed values. the rvalue-constructed `A`'s have adjacent addresses while move-constructed do not, suggesting the former is in-place.

Comment: To be more specific, I can't think of a reasonable scenario where someone would create an rvalue _and pass it to a function_ without the intention of the object being moveable. I'm not talking about `A &&a = ...;`, because if you try to pass `a` to a function, it is an lvalue.

Comment: For example, in your demo, it seems like we could use move constructions in place of the four copy constructions that happen. The temporaries/xvalues that we pass in would get moved anyway if we called `g(A)` instead of `f(A &&)`, so how could this cause a problem?

Comment: @JeremyB. "I can't think of a reasonable scenario where someone would create an rvalue and pass it to a function without the intention of the object being moveable" - intent is entirely the wrong way to think about it. To the point, why do you think it's different as a function argument? In both cases `a` is an lvalue to the proceeding code, because you can manually inline `f`: `A r /*= f(A()+A())*/; {A&&a=A()+A(); /*f's body*/ A res(a); r=res;}`. Written this way it should be clear why there's a copy if you understand how `a` here is an lvalue in `A res(a)`.

Comment: @JeremyB. regarding my last example, we cannot - the only copy construction used (based on the output) is in the return value of `f`, specifically **when the _returned value_ is constructed**. The returned value is itself _is never assigned, copied or moved_, it's constructed in-place - explicitly with rvalues or implicitly via RVO (alters which side of the call). It's copy-constructed because: 1. `f` _must return or construct a new value_, 2. _the lifetime of `a` exceeds the scope of `f`'s body and result_ and 3. _`a` is an lvalue and `return` takes the place of a constructor for the result_.

Comment: @JeremyB. to add to that, the main difference between value assignment and rvalue assignment in that example is critical to understand: RVO _requires_ a move (or copy) constructor even if it isn't used! The same does not apply to rvalue assignment, it can work _even if assignment and construction is private to the class_. Also to note, you could write `f` like this and it'd work as you originally expected: `A f(A && a) {return (decltype(a)) a;}`. I believe this is the only way to specify the "intent" you're looking for due to the above 3 conditions (and a fancy way to avoid `std::move`).

Comment: You say "intent is entirely the wrong way to think about it," but intent does seem to matter when we pass an rvalue into `g`. Also, you ask why it is different as a function argument. That's because storage duration-aware automatic moves only happen for functions anyway. Nice inlining question, but if you replace `A&&a` with `A a`, the value will still get copied when returning, not moved like it would for function return, so I'm not sure the argument is valid. Also, you say "the lifetime of `a` exceeds the scope of `f`'s body and result," but that's not true for your inline version.

Comment: The compiler cannot discern intent. This is why concepts like "intentional programming" exist, which serve to make it clear what the code is doing, not the other way around (to coerce the compiler into desired behavior). "storage duration-aware automatic moves only happen for functions" - can you prove this as i disagree? And with my inlined `f`, a minor adjustment makes it accurate as described: `{A&&a=A()+A(); {/*f's body*/ A res(a); /*return*/ r=res;}}`. You need to understand the distinction between how the contents of a class are exchanged and when / why new class instances appear.

Comment: "The compiler cannot discern intent," unless semantic meaning is attached to syntactic elements, which is what I claim is happening with rvalues. This is why an rvalue is moved (at least conceptually) when passed to `g`, even though the compiler is not explicitly told that that is what the programmer intends to happen, and doing so could have side effects.

Have we started going in circles yet? I haven't bothered to check.

Comment: @JeremyB. more than once lol but making progress. at any rate, I disagree, the semantic meaning with _move_ constructor / assignment is specific to a particular signature, `A(A&&)`. The fact that you're dealing with rvalues _does not_ carry the intent to move in and of itself, except where this signature become relevant (during object construction), but again that's _because of the significance of this signature_ and not because rvalues are being passed around. (edit, only move constructor is relevant, disregard earlier remark about move-assignment signature)

Comment: Okay, I agree that adherence to this syntax–semantics correlation is not required for a program to be well-formed and to behave in a well-defined way. I guess that means it is at most a convention. The STL seems to use the convention that rvalue-reference arguments may be modified. (See, for example, the overloads added to std::string::operator+ in C++11.) So I guess my question is now, are there any examples (in the STL or elsewhere) where this convention is not used? And are there any such examples where adopting the convention would make the code more complicated or cause other problems?

Comment: @JeremyB. It's sounding like a whole new question, just on considering the depth and specificity of this answer (and comments) so far... That said, which convention specifically - _that rvalue-reference arguments may be modified_? In short the convention exists for the newly-constructed object to _steal_ the state of the rvalue argument; the only time you _wouldn't_ need to modify the source temporary object is when the moved data is trivial to move (eg, a smart pointer would not apply because you have to consider _two_ destructor calls) and other times (POD-only struct), move basically = copy

Comment: eg, a string object is a type of smart pointer. it will allocate memory for the _contents_ and deallocate it when the container object goes out of scope / is deleted. consider a move operation on a string container: once a move constructor / assignment is selected from the syntax / expression used, the objective is for the new container to deallocate the memory, and the old container to be told not to bother anymore. this "convention" is only unnecessary, generally, when it doesn't matter if the destructor is called twice for the same contents. typically that's POD structs and basic types.