# What's causing this segmation Fault? pass by refrence, move return

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, c++14, pass-by-reference, move-semantics

I have the following code:

```
#ifndef VECTOR_H
#define VECTOR_H

#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <cmath>

template<typename T>
inline constexpr T &&dot(const sf::Vector2<T> &v1, const sf::Vector2<T> &v2)
{
    return v1.x * v2.x + v1.y * v2.y;
}

template<typename T>
inline constexpr T &&abs(const sf::Vector2<T> &v)
{
    return sqrt(dot(v, v));
}

template<typename T>
inline constexpr sf::Vector2<T> &&norm(const sf::Vector2<T> &v)
{
    return v/abs(v);
}


#endif // VECTOR_H
```

calling `norm(sf::Vector2<float>{1, 0})` produces a Segmentation fault, on the line `return sqrt(dot(v, v));` I'm unsure what is causing this, however I have verified its related to the passing/returning of the values in the functions

as the following runs with out error:

```
#ifndef VECTOR_H
#define VECTOR_H

#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <cmath>

template<typename T>
inline constexpr T dot(const sf::Vector2<T> v1, const sf::Vector2<T> v2)
{
    return v1.x * v2.x + v1.y * v2.y;
}

template<typename T>
inline constexpr T abs(const sf::Vector2<T> v)
{
    return sqrt(dot(v, v));
}

template<typename T>
inline constexpr sf::Vector2<T> norm(const sf::Vector2<T> v)
{
    return v/abs(v);
}


#endif // VECTOR_H
```

Clearly I'm missing some rule about the new syntax, however I'm not sure what it is.

Comment: returning an rvalue reference ≠ move return value

Comment: I'm generally using these function for inline math, and to set variables, my understanding is the move return is more efficient in this case, is there a way I can maintain this efficient and avoid the segmentation fault problem?

Comment: Or do you mean because I'm not using local variables that I shouldn't be using the move return value?? i.e. I should only use it to return a local variable?

Comment: Move will be done by the compiler if the return type has a move constructor.  You are trying to return a reference to a temporary.  This is just invalid (no matter whether it's rvalue or lvalue reference).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [return by rvalue reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13430831/return-by-rvalue-reference)

Comment: You compiler should have actually warned you about this.  Using Clang on a similar piece of code I immediately get `warning: returning reference to local temporary object` (even without any warnings enabled) or [see it live on Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/iKracAMeZs3GTAyZ).

Comment: @glenflet As others mentioned, you should not return a reference to a temporary. However you should accept by const reference if you are not modifying the argument. So you should add `&` to the argument of all the functions: `inline constexpr T abs(const sf::Vector2<T>& v)`